# Take over browser from selenium session

Tags: selenium, codeception

I'm not sure if there is a term for what I'm trying to do. I currently have a test suite using codeception for a php application. What I would like to do is be able to either of the following:

- watch the browser automation in an actual browser
- take over the browser at a specific point ( Sort of like a hand over from the script to the browser to allow me to continue to run a session )

Is this possible? If so what is it called in the selenium documentation

Answer (score 0):

a) Selenium runs the actual browser and you can see what it is doing unless you configured Selenium to run some headless browser (but I don't know anything about headless browsers supported by Selenium);

b) Use Codeception's [pauseExecution](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#pauseExecution) method to stop execution at specific point.

Documentation:

> Pauses test execution in debug mode. To proceed test press “ENTER” in
>   console.
>
> This method is useful while writing tests, since it allows you to
>   inspect the current page in the middle of a test case.